# Stop CloudFormation rebuilding an AMI each time I deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS CloudFormation stack that broadly builds a custom AMI containing the AWS CLI:

```yaml
Resources:
  pipelineImageBuilder:
    Type: AWS::ImageBuilder::ImageRecipe
    Properties:
      Components:
        - ComponentArn: arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:aws:component/aws-cli-version-2-linux/1.0.2
      Name: Nextflow AMI
      ParentImage: ami-03db9b2aac6af477d
      Version: 1.0.1
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: pipelineStack/pipelineImageBuilder
  pipelineImage:
    Type: AWS::ImageBuilder::Image
    Properties:
      InfrastructureConfigurationArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - infrastructureConfig
          - Arn
      ImageRecipeArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - pipelineImageBuilder
          - Arn
    DependsOn:
      - pipelineImageBuilder
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: pipelineStack/pipelineImage
```

Unfortunately, unlike other CloudFormation updates, whenever I update this stack, the entire AMI gets rebuilt from scratch, even if none of the properties are changed. This takes about 20 minutes and costs me money for doing this.

Is there some way to tell CloudFormation to not rebuild this AMI unless some of its properties have changed?

Comment: If nothing has changed, then why do you update the stack?

Comment: I mean when I change *other* resources in the stack that don't relate to this image.

Comment: You maybe need to decouple your image from the rest of the template. Basically extract it to its own template and stack.